# Redraw same image on canvas

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I'm making a chess game. My current idea is after move one piece, I will redraw all board(This may be bad at now)

I have a problem with redraw image, one piece image only draw once time at first and never redraw.

Here is my `drawPiece()` function:

```
drawPieces() {
        const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        const piecesOnBoard = this.boardStatus.split("_");
        for (let key in this.images) {
            const image = this.images[key];
            image[1].onload = function () {
                for (let i = 0; i < piecesOnBoard.length; i++) {
                    let x = piecesOnBoard[i].charAt(0);
                    let y = piecesOnBoard[i].charAt(1);
                    let piece = piecesOnBoard[i].substring(2);
                    if (image[0] === piece) {
                        ctx.drawImage(image[1], (Canvas.CELL_SIZE + 1) * y + 1, (Canvas.CELL_SIZE + 1) * x + 1, Canvas.CELL_SIZE, Canvas.CELL_SIZE);
                        console.log("draw " + image[1] + 'done');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And then, after move one piece, I draw board again by call :

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight);// clear all canvas
board.drawBlankBoard();                                      // redraw blank board - This working
board.drawPieces();                                          // redraw piece image - this NOT working
```

I have 2 question:

1. How to redraw same image (solve my problem) ?
2. What solution can improve performance rather than my current one ?

Thank for help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onload` callback will not fire again once the image has loaded unless you change the `src`

Change the function to what is in the snippet below.

You have used some old school patterns, some pointers regarding your code

- Use [`for of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Don't use [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)
- Access characters in strings via bracket notation. eg `str[idx]` rather than `str.charAt(idx)`
- Use [`String.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) rather than [`String.subString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

### Snippet

```
const ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d'); // do once 


drawPieces() {  
    const C_SIZE = Canvas.CELL_SIZE;
    const status = this.boardStatus.split("_");
    for (const image of Object.values(this.images)) {
        for (const pieceOnBoard of status) {
            if (image[0] === pieceOnBoard.slice(2)) {
                const x = pieceOnBoard[0] * (C_SIZE + 1) + 1;
                const y = pieceOnBoard[1] * (C_SIZE + 1) + 1;
                ctx.drawImage(image[1], y, x, C_SIZE, C_SIZE);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: thank for hint, I'm newbie JavaScript. I never code JavaScript before. More importance, Do you have a solution that solves my problem ?

Comment: @Puskin from the information in your question, this answer does solve your problem

Comment: Oh my got, thank you so much. I thought you just improved the code for me without the solution. Sorry and thank you so much. One proplem. I see on canvas tutorial, it said Make sure photos are loaded before draw. That's why i have onload() callback.

Comment: And for second question, What solution can improve performance rather than my current one ?. Just move one piece with out redraw all canvas

Comment: @Puskin Load all images at start, using one function.  For each image you load increase a counter, For each load event decrease that counter. When in a load event and the counter becomes 0 then all images have loaded and you can start the game. You must also listen the error event. If there is an error then the counter will not reach 0, in that case what to do is up to you. In terms of performance there is a lot you can do. The answer already improved performance a tiny bit. Best way to improve performance is to experiment. You have not provided enough info to further improve performance

Comment: I have no experience about canvas. After image load. Every time i draw image again, does this take alot of time ? And how much timewhen i draw whole board like this(draw about 30 line and 32 piece) ? Thank you so much !!!!!